# SuppressDescription Removes All Columns but the Name

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I'm  using `mod_autoindex`  for some  time with  success (fancy  index).
However  since I  see  no use  for my  "Description"  column, I  thought
I'd  remove  it.  According  to the  [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions),  there  is  the
`SuppressDescription`  to do  that.  So I  go  and add  this  line to  a
*.htaccess* file:

```
IndexOptions SuppressDescription
```

It did  remove that column but  also remove every other  column. It only
left a  `<ul>` of the names  of the files.  No more fancy listing.  If I
remove that line I will have back the standard "Name | Modified | Size |
Description" listing.

Any  ideas of  how  can I  track  that,  and solve  to  only remove  the
description column leaver the other 3 untouched?

#### Before:

[image: before]

#### After:

[image: after]

Comment: what if you use: `IndexOptions +SuppressDescription`

Comment: @bangal Solved the problem. Please post as answer so I can give you the points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the directive with correct syntax (`+` for enabling and `-` for disabling an option) as needed by apache 2.4 . You are missing a `+` sign here:

`IndexOptions +SuppressDescription`

**IndexOptions Directive**  (quoted from apache 2.4 doc)

- Description:  Various configuration settings for directory indexing
- Syntax:   IndexOptions [+|-]option [[+|-]option]...
- Default:  By default, no options are enabled.
- Context:  server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess
- Override: Indexes
- Status:   Base
- Module:   mod_autoindex

Please have a look here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html

Comment: Thanks you very much, this shows my inexperience with Apache. You solved a very inconvenient problem I was facing. Best wishes

Comment: I'm so low in reputation in this site that I can't even upvote  but I will do when I can. Sorry!

Comment: You are welcome. This was a major syntax change in Apache 2.4 and many made the same mistake. It is a bit tricky. A `+`  sign aktivates an option, and `- `sign deactivates it. Glad that it helped.